# How to display Custom popup instead of UIMenuController

Tags: iphone, ios, uimenucontroller

I am creating an app that contain `UITextView` that contain large amount of text. and when i double tap any text than its default behavior will happen and show `UIMenuController`. like this,

[image]

But i want to display custom popup instead of `UIMenuController` like this,

[image]

How can i do this?

**UPDATE**

Which method will called when this `UIMenuController` open?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267296/how-do-i-add-a-custom-uimenuitem-to-the-uimenucontroller-in-a-uitextview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537795/uimenucontroller-custom-items

Comment: @DharaParekh As i said i dont want to add any more option in UIMenucontroller but instead of it i want to replace it with my pop up

Answer (score 0):

Check this accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283765/display-uimenucontroller-in-editingdidbegin-of-a-uitextfield).

You can subclass UITextField and override the below method to disable whichever action you want :

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(cut:))
    {
        return NO; 
    }
    else if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
     ... //etc etc

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

and display your own using the following code:

```
UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[menu setTargetRect:textField.frame inView:textField.superview];
[menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" action:@selector(test)],
                            nil]];
[menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

and in the `canPeformAction:withSender:` method you can return `YES` for the selector `Test`.